# CreateThread x3000 returns stdout handle

Tags: c, winapi

I have problem creating thousands of threads and closing it.
Look at this code:

```
HANDLE threadHandles[i];
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    CreateThread(0, 0, &func, 0, CREATE_SUSPENDED, threadHandles[i]);
    printf("%i - %i\n", i, threadHandles[i]);
    CloseHandle(threadHandles[i])
}
printf("Last Error is %i", GetLastError());
```

It should proceed this output:

```
0 - 236423
1 - 23456236
2 - 2373547 
3 - 73521346 
4 - 23456775
5 - 78543683465 
...
2998 - 754752
2999 - 23462346
Last Error is 0
```

like this.

But actually it will print nothing. Why? Because one of the created threads had a conflict with stdout handle. 
I realized it using this code:

```
HANDLE stdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
HANDLE threadHandles[i];
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    CreateThread(0, 0, &func, 0, CREATE_SUSPENDED, threadHandles[i]);
    printf("%i - %i\n", i, threadHandles[i]);
    if(threadHandles[i] != stdout) // I have stdout == 12 on my machine
        CloseHandle(threadHandles[i])
}
```

and it worked like this:

```
0 - 236423
1 - 23456236
2 - 2373547 
3 - 0 
4 - 23456775
5 - 78543683465 
...
2998 - 0
2999 - 23462346
Last Error is 6
```

Where is the problem? Why there is a conflict between created handles and existing standard handles?

Comment: In the question title and provided output, you suggest the loop count should be 3,000 - but in the code, it's only 1,000. Is this the exact code you're using?

Comment: it's just an example

Comment: you print threadId instead thread handle. but even your printf incorrect - `0 - 236423` ? `236423` can not be thread id which is always have form `4*n`

Answer (score 3):

The thread handle is returned by the function! The last parameter receives the thread id, not the handle.

```
HANDLE threadHandles[1000] = { 0 };
UINT i;
for (i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    DWORD threadId;
    threadHandles[i] = CreateThread(0, 0, &func, 0, /*CREATE_SUSPENDED*/0, &threadId);
    if (!threadHandles[i])
    {
        printf("Failed to create thread, error %u\n", GetLastError());
        break;
    }
    printf("Thread #%u: handle=%p id=%u\n", i, threadHandles[i], threadId);
    // Not closing the handle here so the example will show unique thread handles and ids: CloseHandle(threadHandles[i]), threadHandles[i] = NULL;
}

// TODO: Wait for threads or do some other work?

for (i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    if (threadHandles[i])
        CloseHandle(threadHandles[i]);
```

On my machine this prints

```
Thread #0: handle=0000002C id=16424
Thread #1: handle=00000030 id=21192
Thread #2: handle=00000034 id=21180
Thread #3: handle=00000038 id=17336
Thread #4: handle=0000003C id=21184
Thread #5: handle=00000040 id=4460
...
Thread #991: handle=00000FE8 id=12280
Thread #992: handle=00000FEC id=20360
Thread #993: handle=00000FF0 id=20328
Thread #994: handle=00000FF4 id=16060
Thread #995: handle=00000FF8 id=4556
Thread #996: handle=00000FFC id=20296
Thread #997: handle=00001004 id=10316
Thread #998: handle=00001008 id=20604
Thread #999: handle=0000100C id=20264
```

Comment: Can't it be returned to lpThreadId parameter of CreateThread?
UPD: I edit my code with your changes but now I have error 8 and output:
    0 - 236423
    1 - 23456236
    2 - 2373547 
    3 - 34573
    4 - 23456775
    5 - 78543683465 
    ...
    2998 - 0
    2999 - 0

Comment: From the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453(v=vs.85).aspx) - "By default, every thread has one megabyte of stack space. Therefore, you can create at most 2,048 threads." So, creating 3,000 threads won't work.

Also, the thread ID and thread handle are different things.

Comment: You should also keep in mind that when the thread has finished and all the handles to it have been closed then both the handle value and the thread id might get reused. The thread id is only valid as long as there is a valid handle open to the thread.

Comment: On my machine both your and mine code break at the 900 threads limit! What's the problem?

Comment: Running out of memory perhaps? Uncomment the CloseHandle line in the first loop and it should work if func() is a fast function.

Comment: Still error 8 after uncommenting 0_0
_
And every 100-150 threads had the same thread handle!

Comment: simply close thread handle not enough. need or resume thread or terminate it, before close it handle. otherwise we have zombie (suspended but alive) threads in system

Comment: 8 is ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY. And the *handle value* can be the same if the old thread has ended and the handles have been closed. Handles values can be reused once the object itself goes away, that's just the way it works.

Comment: RbMm, thanks you, that was the problem. I replaced CloseHandle by TerminateHandle.

Comment: TerminateThread is not a real solution. Either resume the thread or don't start it suspended in the first place. In normal workflow you close the thread handle and the thread finally goes away when its callback function returns or calls ExitThread. TerminateThread will leak memory on some versions of Windows.